# On an existence of a certain compact set in a Polish group

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure defined on a Polish group $G$. Does there exists an equivalent measure $\lambda$ and a compact set $F$ with $\lambda(F)>0$ such that for each $X \subseteq F$ and each $g \in G$ with $gX \subseteq F$ the condition $\lambda(X)=\lambda(gX)$ holds true?